# LoDash / Underscorejs not global variable

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Basically I want to use Lo dash or Underscore (preferably lo-dash) however, with my system it is important that I don't load the variables globally and use them anonymously. If I can't use anon, then at least keeping the current version on the page and not overriding it.

Preferably it would be completely anonymously, any ideas on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated

It's not possible to use require either

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#noConflict ?

Comment: Ah I hadn't realised, thanks. For example if _ is undefined before running noConflict I guess it would remove it?

Comment: Although if possible to be completely "anon" would be better I think

Comment: What does that even mean? You can do `yournamespace._ = _.noConflict()`...?

Comment: It never gets loaded on to the window, basically if I did something like 
(function (){
var x = 'something';
})();

I wouldn't have access to x outside of that ....

Comment: `noConflict` removes it from `window`. http://jsfiddle.net/VS4H6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a use case for `_.noConflict()`.

```
(function() {
    var x = _.noConflict();

    // logs undefined
    console.info('lodash', window._);

}());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VS4H6/)

Comment: It's a great answer now! It appeared in the low quality review queue because it was virtually just a link. Now that you have edited the question, it's all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash-cli https://github.com/lodash/lodash-cli, it is possible to do this completely making a custom build wrapping the output of Lo-dash using the IIFE option.

Normal is something like iife="!function(window,undefined){%output%}(this)"

Using lodash-cli it is also possible to only build functions from lodash which is desired.